# How to recieve answer from UDP server on Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, udp

Have an UDP echo server(C#). I am tring to send info to it from android application(Kotlin). But my code not receiving answer from server

```
        val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
        var buffer = ByteArray(2048)
        val socket = DatagramSocket()
        socket.broadcast = true
        val sendData = messageStr.toByteArray()
        val sendPacket = DatagramPacket(sendData,sendData.size
            ,InetAddress.getByName(Settings.RemoteHost), Settings.RemotePort)
        socket.send(sendPacket)
        var packet = DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.size)
        socket.receive(packet)
        println("received = " + packet.data) // empty
```

`socket.receive(packet)` not working. Nothing happening, as if the line is being ignored.

Looking any working variant

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Did you get an error? Did nothing happen? Did it hang? Did you verify that your server actually sent a response back? Did you verify that the client actually received the packet (considering you're using UDP)? Please give more details about your problem.

Comment: Nothing happend -> nothing receiving. Server working good, check it using other udp clients.